# Do we need to make the response secure?

Tags: api, security, oauth-2.0, response, access-token

Most of the time we are using JWT access token validation to make sure that the request to e.g. an API is secure. However do we need to make sure that the response that comes back from that system (or API) is secure enough? Do we need to be worry? and how should we mitigate it?

appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: #1 What do you mean by `response that comes back from that system (or API) is secure enough`? If you consume some endpoint of aws rest api, you are getting a string which will be parsed for your http client. #2 Do you think that this string could be malicious and affect to the client app?

Answer (score 1):

As usually with those things, the answer is it depends ;)

1. Who is the owner of the API that you're calling? If you're calling your own API then you can be pretty sure about the validity and safeness of the response. If you're calling a third-party API then you might add some checks. Maybe scan files for malicious code if you're downloading any files from that API? Or check whether the response is not trying to inject any code, etc. It might not be the easiest thing to do, though.
2. Are you using a secure connection to the API? If you use SSL then you're sure that no one has tampered with the response. Additionally you can verify certificate chains to verify that you're connecting to the right API endpoint and not to a malicious one. If you're not using SSL then you might want to verify the response from the API, whether it's been tampered or not. How to do that verification again might not be trivial, but maybe the response can be signed?
3. Where is the client which is talking to the API? If you have a backend client talking to an API then you should not worry that response might be altered at client side. If you have an SPA running in a browser, then the response might be altered by a man-in-the-browser attack. Such response can be altered even if you use SSL to connect to the API, as SSL is terminated in the browser and a compromised user-agent will grant the attacker access to the decrypted API response. You can also have an XSS attack which alters responses in your app. Again, to protect from that threat you would need responses to be signed, or have another way of verifying integrity.

One way of verifying integrity of a response is to use signed JWTs with asymmetric signing. The API can sign the response with its private key, and then you can verify whether it's not been tampered with. E.g. the [JARM](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-jarm.html) spec uses that for OAuth flow responses.